# Бегущая строка на ASP-странице

Tags: c#, asp.net

День добрый!
Есть веб-приложение с использованием ASP.NET и БД на PostgreSQL (Прилагаю архив во вложении). Так вот, нужно сделать бегущую строку, в которой будет отображаться информация о последней добавленной записи в приложении. Помогите, пожалуйста, новичку с реализацией бегущей строки! Ломаю голову, не могу придумать, как правильно её сделать...

З.Ы. Прилагаю ссылку на файлообменник
https://yadi.sk/d/-Q4pzpmY33w9ga

Comment: [marquee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Comment: @Grundy я так понимаю, что JS тоже нужно задействовать?

Comment: @Dremjke Нет, это чистый HTML

Comment: @Grundy А не хотите это как ответ оформить? Тем более по вашей ссылке есть прекрасный пример. Скопипастите и ответ готов. А вот, к примеру, про этот тэг впервые от вас услышал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое решение: воспользоваться тегом [`<marquee>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee). Недостатком этого решения является то, что данные элемент является устаревшим, и не рекомендованным к использованию. Поэтому вполне вероятно в будущих версиях браузеров он не будет поддерживаться.

```html
<marquee>This text will scroll from right to left</marquee>
```

Кроме этого возможно решение с использованием [css-анимации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation) и, например, свойства [text-indent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent), либо позиции внутреннего элемента:

Пример:

```css
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1em;
  animation: 20s linear infinite marquee;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    text-indent: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    text-indent: -50%;
  }
}
.marquee-position {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.marquee-position > span {
  position: absolute;
  animation: 15s linear infinite marquee-position;
}
@keyframes marquee-position {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">This text will scroll from right to left</div>

<div class="marquee-position"><span>This text will scroll from right to left</span>
</div>
```